# Subtracting an older textfile from a newer

Tags: bash, sed

How would one remove the contents of an older copy of a file from a newer one?

For example:

Given a mailfile, which is copied and work is done on the copy. 
During the work the original mailfile grows in size. 
How would you remove the old mails stored in the older file from the new one.

I imagine you could count the lines and remove that number of lines from the top of the new file? Is there a way to do this easily in bash?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tail -n+<NUM_LINE> file` to print `file` starting at line `NUM_LINE`.

To remove the number of lines of `mailfile1` from `mailfile2` saving the result to `mailfile2.new`:

```
tail -n+$(( $(wc -l <mailfile1) + 1)) mailfile2 > mailfile2.new
```

- `wc -l <mailfile1` prints the number of lines of `mailfile1`
- `$(( $(wc -l <mailfile1) + 1))` prints the number of the lines of `mailfile1` + 1

Comment: Thanks Freddy.  Your answer would have been the cleanest. I used `sed -e "1,$(wc -l $mailfile1 | cut -f1 -d ' ')d" < $mailfile2 > $mailfile2.new` before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files are formatted identically (on Linux this must include capitalization), such as one email address per line, `comm` will do what you want:

```
$ cat old <(echo '--') new
foo@example.com
farkle@example.com
flotz@example.com
bar@example.com
--
farkle@example.com
bar@example.com
flotz@example.com
frammitz@example.com
glop@example.com
yurbine@example.com
$ comm -i13 <(sort old) <(sort new)
frammitz@example.com
glop@example.com
yurbine@example.com
```

The `-13` option to `comm` tells it to not display addresses that are only in `old` (`-1`) and to not display addresses that are in both files (`-3`).  That therefore leaves the output as showing only the addresses that are found *only* in `new`.

If you're on BSD, you can add `comm`'s `-i` switch to do a case-insensitive match, if your files are not already normalized with respect to alphabetic case.